# Redis: Find the intersection of a range and an unordered set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis

I have an ordered set - items that I've scored and added to my redis db via the gem 'redis' like so:

```
Item.each { |item|
  $redis.zadd("scores", item.score, item.id)
}
```

And a set full of items with a key based on the tag id.

```
Tag.each { |tag|
  tag.items.each { |item|
     $redis.sadd("tag_#{tag.id}", item.id)
  }
}
```

I'm trying to get all items with a score of **x or above** and intersect that with all items that have a specific tag.  I don't need the result to be sorted.  I'm not sure that I need to use an ordered set in the first place, but it seems like an efficient way to store and retrieve the results.

What is the best way to find the intersection of a range and a set with Redis?

Comment: I was having a problem with Redis 2.2.5.  When I tried to call the zinterstore command, I would get this error. "Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6379: Connection refused."  After upgrading to redis 2.4.13, this error went away.

Comment: Another note - on redis 2.4.13, I was unable to use the results of a sunionstore in a zinterstore.  Upgrading again fixed this.  Now on version 2.6.10 all works well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key point is the sorted set commands also accept normal set as parameters. So you can intersect first with the set, and then use normal range commands to filter based on the score.

**Example:**

```
# Populate some sorted set and set
./redis-cli zadd scores 1 a 2 b 3 c 4 d 5 e 6 f 7 g 8 h
(integer) 8
./redis-cli sadd tag_1 a c d g h
(integer) 5

# Here you need to use a weight clause to avoid altering the score
./redis-cli zinterstore res 2 scores tag_1 weights 1 0
(integer) 5

# Now fetch the expected items (here we want items with score >= 4)
./redis-cli zrangebyscore res 4 +inf withscores
1) "d"
2) "4"
3) "g"
4) "7"
5) "h"
6) "8"

# Finally drop the temporary result
./redis-cli del res
(integer) 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip on deleting the temporary store

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of a way to get a range first, and intersect later. What you can do, though, is make an intersection of the sets and then do the range:

```
ZINTERSTORE items_with_tag_foo 2 items tag_foo AGGREGATE MAX
ZRANGEBYSCORE items_with_tag_foo 17 +inf
```